# Return the base64 representation of an image

Tags: php, base64, barcode

I have the following code taken from David S. Tufts barcode PHP script:

```
function barcode( $filepath = "", $text = "0", $size = "20", $orientation = "horizontal", $code_type = "code128", $print = false, $SizeFactor = 1 ) {
    $code_string = "";
    $chksum      = 104;
    // Must not change order of array elements as the checksum depends on the array's key to validate final code
    $code_array  = [
        " "       => "212222",
        "!"       => "222122",
        "\""      => "222221",
        "#"       => "121223",
        "$"       => "121322",
        "%"       => "131222",
        "&"       => "122213",
        "'"       => "122312",
        "("       => "132212",
        ")"       => "221213",
        "*"       => "221312",
        "+"       => "231212",
        ","       => "112232",
        "-"       => "122132",
        "."       => "122231",
        "/"       => "113222",
        "0"       => "123122",
        "1"       => "123221",
        "2"       => "223211",
        "3"       => "221132",
        "4"       => "221231",
        "5"       => "213212",
        "6"       => "223112",
        "7"       => "312131",
        "8"       => "311222",
        "9"       => "321122",
        ":"       => "321221",
        ";"       => "312212",
        "<"       => "322112",
        "="       => "322211",
        ">"       => "212123",
        "?"       => "212321",
        "@"       => "232121",
        "A"       => "111323",
        "B"       => "131123",
        "C"       => "131321",
        "D"       => "112313",
        "E"       => "132113",
        "F"       => "132311",
        "G"       => "211313",
        "H"       => "231113",
        "I"       => "231311",
        "J"       => "112133",
        "K"       => "112331",
        "L"       => "132131",
        "M"       => "113123",
        "N"       => "113321",
        "O"       => "133121",
        "P"       => "313121",
        "Q"       => "211331",
        "R"       => "231131",
        "S"       => "213113",
        "T"       => "213311",
        "U"       => "213131",
        "V"       => "311123",
        "W"       => "311321",
        "X"       => "331121",
        "Y"       => "312113",
        "Z"       => "312311",
        "["       => "332111",
        "\\"      => "314111",
        "]"       => "221411",
        "^"       => "431111",
        "_"       => "111224",
        "\`"      => "111422",
        "a"       => "121124",
        "b"       => "121421",
        "c"       => "141122",
        "d"       => "141221",
        "e"       => "112214",
        "f"       => "112412",
        "g"       => "122114",
        "h"       => "122411",
        "i"       => "142112",
        "j"       => "142211",
        "k"       => "241211",
        "l"       => "221114",
        "m"       => "413111",
        "n"       => "241112",
        "o"       => "134111",
        "p"       => "111242",
        "q"       => "121142",
        "r"       => "121241",
        "s"       => "114212",
        "t"       => "124112",
        "u"       => "124211",
        "v"       => "411212",
        "w"       => "421112",
        "x"       => "421211",
        "y"       => "212141",
        "z"       => "214121",
        "{"       => "412121",
        "|"       => "111143",
        "}"       => "111341",
        "~"       => "131141",
        "DEL"     => "114113",
        "FNC 3"   => "114311",
        "FNC 2"   => "411113",
        "SHIFT"   => "411311",
        "CODE C"  => "113141",
        "FNC 4"   => "114131",
        "CODE A"  => "311141",
        "FNC 1"   => "411131",
        "Start A" => "211412",
        "Start B" => "211214",
        "Start C" => "211232",
        "Stop"    => "2331112",
    ];
    $code_keys   = array_keys( $code_array );
    $code_values = array_flip( $code_keys );
    for ( $X = 1; $X <= strlen( $text ); $X ++ ) {
        $activeKey   = substr( $text, ( $X - 1 ), 1 );
        $code_string .= $code_array[ $activeKey ];
        $chksum      = ( $chksum + ( $code_values[ $activeKey ] * $X ) );
    }
    $code_string .= $code_array[ $code_keys[ ( $chksum - ( intval( $chksum / 103 ) * 103 ) ) ] ];
    $code_string = "211214" . $code_string . "2331112";
    // Pad the edges of the barcode
    $code_length = 20;
    if ( $print ) {
        $text_height = 30;
    } else {
        $text_height = 0;
    }

    for ( $i = 1; $i <= strlen( $code_string ); $i ++ ) {
        $code_length = $code_length + (integer) ( substr( $code_string, ( $i - 1 ), 1 ) );
    }
    if ( strtolower( $orientation ) == "horizontal" ) {
        $img_width  = $code_length * $SizeFactor;
        $img_height = $size;
    } else {
        $img_width  = $size;
        $img_height = $code_length * $SizeFactor;
    }
    $image = imagecreate( $img_width, $img_height + $text_height );
    $black = imagecolorallocate( $image, 0, 0, 0 );
    $white = imagecolorallocate( $image, 255, 255, 255 );
    imagefill( $image, 0, 0, $white );
    if ( $print ) {
        imagestring( $image, 5, 31, $img_height, $text, $black );
    }
    $location = 10;
    for ( $position = 1; $position <= strlen( $code_string ); $position ++ ) {
        $cur_size = $location + ( substr( $code_string, ( $position - 1 ), 1 ) );
        if ( strtolower( $orientation ) == "horizontal" ) {
            imagefilledrectangle( $image, $location * $SizeFactor, 0, $cur_size * $SizeFactor, $img_height,
                ( $position % 2 == 0 ? $white : $black ) );
        } else {
            imagefilledrectangle( $image, 0, $location * $SizeFactor, $img_width, $cur_size * $SizeFactor, ( $position % 2 == 0 ? $white : $black ) );
        }
        $location = $cur_size;
    }
    // Draw barcode to the screen or save in a file
    if ( $filepath == "" ) {
        header( 'Content-type: image/png' );
        imagepng( $image );
        imagedestroy( $image );
    } else {
        imagepng( $image, $filepath );
        imagedestroy( $image );
    }
}

barcode( "", "foo", "20", "horizontal", "code128", true, "1" );
```

This returns a barcode image:
[barcode1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CG25n.png)

How can I recode this and return a bytecode text like:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGMAAAAyAQMAAAByJ/eEAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAAUElEQVQokWP4f7qa2/dFbmvb5i77BwyjPBw8JECYN////884eP/YDx84gCQ3c14xEs9mPrI+hgPIPPt/SCpnzplXbA/nHT544Ec9US4bVjwABCIBluioK1YAAAAASUVORK5CYII=
```

instead of an image?

I have already tried changing the line:

`imagepng($image);`

to

`return "data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode(imagepng($image));`

but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with bytecode. What you mistakenly call [tag:bytecode] is actually [tag:data-uri]. Also, please describe "doesn't seem to work" specifically: how does not working exhibit itself? What does the string end uo as? Or is there an error? Does it look okay to you but browser refuses it? What happens?

Comment: yes Amadan you are right. Thank you for correcting it. What I meant was "data-uri". What I meant with "doesn't seem to work" is that it returns an error instead of showing a rendered image. I tried editing my question but the editor wont allow me to make edits. I apologize for being vague with my questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is turn on output buffering before you make your calls, then get the buffer contents.

```
    $contents = null;

    ob_start();  // Start output buffering

    imagealphablending($resource, true);
    imagesavealpha($resource, true);
    imagepng($resource);

    $contents = ob_get_flush(); // Stop output buffering
```

Comment: Thank you @delboy1978uk for taking the time to answer but I have solved it by doing `code`ob_start();
    imagepng($image);
    $image_data = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return base64_encode($image_data);`code`

Comment: yes, thats exactly what i mean, glad you got it working. Can you mark this as the right answer please? :-)